# real_escape_string not cleaning up entered text

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I thought the proper way to "sanitize" incoming data from an HTML form *before* entering it into a mySQL database was to use `real_escape_string` on it in the PHP script, like this:

```
$newsStoryHeadline = $_POST['newsStoryHeadline'];
$newsStoryHeadline = $mysqli->real_escape_string($newsStoryHeadline);
$storyDate = $_POST['storyDate'];
$storyDate = $mysqli->real_escape_string($storyDate);
$storySource = $_POST['storySource'];
$storySource = $mysqli->real_escape_string($storySource);
// etc.
```

And once that's done you could just insert the data to the DB like this:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO NewsStoriesTable (Headline, Date, DateAdded, Source, StoryCopy) VALUES ('".$newsStoryHeadline."', '".$storyDate."', '".$dateAdded."', '".$storySource."', '".$storyText."')");
```

So I thought doing this would take care of cleaning up all the invisible "junk" characters that may be coming in with your submitted text.

However, I just pasted some text I copied from a web-page into my HTML form, clicked "submit" - which ran the above script and inserted that text into my DB - but when I read that text *back* from the DB, I discovered that this piece of text *did* still have junk characters in it, such as `â€“`. 
And those junk characters of course caused the PHP script I wrote that *retrieves* the information from the DB to crash.

So what am I doing wrong?

Is using `real_escape_string` *not* the way to go here?  Or should I be using it in conjunction with something else?
OR, is there something I should be doing (like more escaping) when reading reading data back out from the the mySQL database?

(I should mention that I'm an Objective-C developer, not a PHP/mySQL developer, but I've unfortunately been given this task to do some DB stuff - hence my question...) 
thanks!

Comment: You should be using parametrized queries instead of `real_escape_string`, for one thing. Have you set the character set correctly for your pages?

Comment: hmm, not quite sure what you mean by "have you set character set correctly" - what would that statement look like? (I should mention that I'm an Objective-C developer, not a PHP/mySQL developer, but I've unfortunately been given this task to do some DB stuff...)

Comment: Where did you get that idea of "cleaning" "junk characters"?

Comment: I got the idea they're "junk" cause they're _not_ visible in the original text - but suddenly do show up upon retrieval. That's my idea of "junk" :-) I'm assuming they're formatting type characters? Either way, they're causing my PHP script to crash, so whether we call them "junk" or not, I just need to understand how to handle them :-) So, any ideas?

Comment: @sirab333 `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your `<head>`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - Couple of things: there's no `<head>` in my document. The PHP script I'm using to query the DB creates an *XML* file of the results, not an HTML file. Does XML also need a `<head>`? And should I be doing `echo "<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>` - that sort of thing to create it? And are we talking about doing this in the PHP file that'll generate the output of a query? Is that where it would go?

Comment: @sirab333 You might try something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. How are you viewing the XML file?

Comment: @Waleed- I view my XML in 2 ways: either I type the URL directly into the browser and the file opens there, or I read it into my iPhone App and parse it there. When the XML is "healthy" it displays very nicely as a DOM tree. When it encounters "junk" characters like `â€“` the script fails and I don't get any XML at all - I just get errors. When I go to my Database and manually remove the `â€“` the XML goes back to working nicely. Also, I put this in my code: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` - and I'm still getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong. `mysqli_real_escape_string`’s only intention is to escape certain characters so that the resulting string can be safely used in a [MySQL string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html). That’s it, nothing more, nothing less.

The result should be that exactly the passed data is retained, including ‘junk’. If you don’t want that ‘junk’ in your database, you need to detect, validate, or filter it before passing to to MySQL.

In your case, the ‘junk’ seems to be due to different character encodings: You input data seems to be encoded with UTF-8 while it’s later displayed using [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250). In this scenario, the character `–` (U+2013) would be encoded with 0xE28093 in UTF-8 which would represent the three characters `â`, `€`, and `“` in Windows-1250. [Properly declaring the document’s encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) would probably fix this.

Comment: Ok, I tried addressing the encoding issue by putting `echo "<head><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></head>` into my code - and its still not working. I put this in the PHP script that queries the DB (via `SELECT * FROM NewsStoriesTable) ... etc` and then loops through the result-set's ROWS and echo's everything out as XML. It still fails and gives me errors. But when I manually go into the mySQL db and delete the `â€“` from the entry that has it, everything goes back to working perfectly: my PHP queries run and generate good, error-free XML. Does that shed any more light on the problem?

Comment: @sirab333 The XML declaration comes at the very first, even before the document type declaration. It is also preferred to [send the content encoding via HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#httpheadwhat). And regarding the database, the data in there still may be properly encoded but is only *displayed* with the wrong character encoding. But we will only know if you can supply a hex dump of that data.

Answer (score 1):

Sanitization is a tricky subject, because it never means the same thing depending on the context. :)

`real_escape_string` just makes sure your data can be included in a request (inside quotes, of course) without having the possibility to change the "meaning" of the request.

The [manual page](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) explains what the function really does: it escapes nul characters, line feeds, carriage returns, simple quotes, double quotes, and "Control-Z" (probably the SUBSTITUTE character). So it just inserts a backslash before those characters.

That's it. It "sanitizes" the string so it can be passed unchanged in a request. But it doesn't sanitize it under any other point of view: users can still pass for instance HTML markers, or "strange" characters. You need to make rules depending on what your output format is (most of the time HTML, but HTTP isn't restricted to HTML documents), and what you want to let your users do.

If your code can't handle some characters, or if they have a special meaning in the output format, or if they cause your output to appear "corrupted" in some way, you need to escape or remove them yourself.

You will probably be interested in [`htmlspecialchars`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Control characters generally aren't a problem with HTML. If your output encoding is the same as your input encoding, they won't be displayed and thus won't be an issue for your users (well, maybe for the W3C validator). If you think it is, make your own function to check and remove them.

Comment: OK, that clarifies things a bit. I'll research `html_special_chars` - but will this help with *XML*? Cause that's all I'm trying to get: good, "healthy" XML. My ultimate goal is to simply run some queries on the mySQL database - via a PHP script - and have that script output the query results as XML. Mostly this works perfectly well, but every time the PHP script runs into these "junk" characters, they're causing  it to crash and stop generating XML. I get errors. But its not HTML I'm after - just XML. Let me know if that gives you a better idea of how to help - or where I should look for info

Comment: You can pass `ENT_XML1` in the `flags` bitmask of `htmlspecialchars` (sorry, I mistyped the function name, damn incoherent PHP functions). I'm not sure what it will do differently, as the replacements described in the man page seem enough to sanitize data to put inside XML elements.
That said, you probably should put such data in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` brackets, so XML parsers see it as a raw string.